# Select box doesn't show selected value

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a select box like this, it works and is saved in the database, but after I refresh the page the selected value doesn't appear as selected. Any suggestions?

```
.col-md-6
  %span.label.label-purple{:style => "pointer-events: none; font-size: 14px"} Country Default
  = select_tag :country_default, options_for_select(Location.where(loc_type: "country").map { |country| [country.name, country.loc_code] }),
                                                style: "margin-top: 11px;",
                                                include_blank: "",
                                                class: "country-default select2", data: { select: "select2"}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`options_for_select` has an optional second argument, which will display your selected option, if one has been selected.

```
...options_for_select(Location.where(loc_type: "country").map { |country| 
[country.name, 
country.loc_code]}, @YOURMODEL.country_default)...
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `collection_select` instead of `select_tag` like this:

```
=collection_select :country, :default, Location.where(loc_type: "country"), :loc_code, :name,
  {include_blank: '', selected: 'select2' },
  {class: 'country-default select2', style: 'margin-top: 11px;'}
```

another option is using `select` to generate select boxes.
See the [Action View Helpers](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html#making-select-boxes-with-ease/) Guide

Comment: Thank you for the answer. With this code I have the error: undefined method `map' for :loc_code:Symbol